# Handling jQuery Tabs with Our Own Indexes

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I have created tabs dynamically with my own indexes, but when I try to add the tab, jQuery is giving it's own index.

How do I tell it not to use the default indexing?

Example :

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#dummy-0" > </a></li>
</ul>
<div id="dummy-0"></div>
```

When I try to create it dynamically with my own index '0' it works, but at the same time it generates its own index .

How do I avoid this? Please help me.

Comment: What jQuery code are you using to dynamically add the tab with your index?

Comment: for (var i =0 ; i<5 ; i++){

modul =i ;

jQuery("#fw").tabs("remove", modul);

url = 'a.jsp';

jQuery("#fw").tabs("add",url,"ACD" , modul);

}